# Splitting the column based on alphabets and numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values in one column as shown below.

> ColumnA

```
APPLE1234
ORANGE12
GR445
LE4444
```

My expected output is splitting the values in the column to alphabets and numbers.

Expected output :

```
APPLE      1234
ORANGE     12    
GR         445    
LE         4444
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: I was trying using some regexpression .I don`t have much experience using regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is probably using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("ColumnA", '[A-Za-z]') AS Numbers
      ,REGEXP_REPLACE("ColumnA", '[0-9]') AS Letters
FROM  Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75c32/4/0)

Update: If you don't want to use Regular Expressions you can use `TRANSLATE()`:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE("ColumnA",'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') AS Letters
      ,TRANSLATE("ColumnA",'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','0123456789') AS Numbers
FROM Table1;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75c32/10/0)

Comment: nice one.Is there any way i can do it without using reg exp?